# How to stop automatic rounding of number filed in extjs

Tags: extjs4.1

I am using a extjs number field and it is automatically rounding to 2 digits while saving.
ie. if i enter 3.2356 it will be saved as 3.24.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. using decimalPrecision.

The maximum precision to display after the decimal separator. Defaults to: 2